# How to specify timezone for repeated events in fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I use fullcalendar to have an event calendar for an online guild. We have recurring guild missions twice a week and occasional special events as well. I keep the events in JSON in Zulu time and displayed as local time to help with coordination.

Code Snippet:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Guild Missions",
    "start": "21:15",
    "end": "21:45",
    "dow": [
      0
    ],
    "color": "#00688B"
  },
  {
    "title": "Guild Missions",
    "start": "02:15",
    "end": "02:45",
    "dow": [
      2
    ],
    "color": "#00688B"
  },
  {
    "title": "Event",
    "start": "2015-06-14T02:00:00Z",
    "end": "2015-06-14T06:00:00Z",
    "allDay": false
  },
  <and many more events>
]
```

So one-off events have the Z specification, which shows in EST, PST, etc, but I can't find any examples of using recurring events across timezones to know how to format the guild missions. It's just always a hardcoded 9:15pm Sunday and 2:15am Tuesday instead of showing 2:15pm PST Sunday and 7:15pm PST Monday

Comment: Use a dateString that includes the timezone, and the user's local browser will automatically convert it to their local timezone. See: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp

Comment: @MatthewHerbst That just causes the time to display as midnight. 
{
    "title": "Guild Missions",
    "start": "2015-10-11T21:15:00Z",
    "end": "2015-10-11T21:15:00Z",
    "dow": [
      0
    ],
    "color": "#00688B"
  },
  {
    "title": "Guild Missions",
    "start": "2015-10-13T02:15:00Z",
    "end": "2015-10-13T02:45:00Z",
    "dow": [
      2
    ],
    "color": "#00688B"
  }

Is Sunday at midnight and Tuesday at midnight

Comment: have a look at this [link](http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.6.0/demos/timezones.html), see if it helps you.

Comment: @ItsASine really not sure what your problem is - when I do `console.log(new Date("2015-06-14T06:00:00.000Z"))` it properly converts to my timezone without any extra work.

Answer (score 0):

If you need support for time zones on recurring events, you should use the [rrule plugin](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/rrule-plugin) instead of a [simple recurring object](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/recurring-events). The field "dtstart" can take a zoned date time string like "2023-05-01T14:30:00Z" (UTC).

Sample event object:

```
      {
        id: "eventId",
        title: "eventTitle",
        duration: "01:30",
        rrule: {
          freq: 'weekly',
          interval: 5,
          byweekday: [ 'mo', 'fr' ],
          dtstart: '2023-05-01T14:30:00Z',
          until: '2023-12-01'
        }
      }
```

You can install the rrule plugin from npm and import in your calendar options, just like the day grid or time grid plugins. Here it is the full documentation of rrule: https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule